# how to delete uploaded files from google cloud using slingshot package

Tags: google-cloud-storage, meteor-slingshot

after successfully uploading files on google cloud storage using slingshot package, i didn't find documentation about how to delete files from google cloud throw my application. is there any idea to work around ? Thanks.